# Dynamically replace values of a column based on available values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have this data frame

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(c1 = sample(c(0:3,NA), 50, replace = T), c2 = sample(c(0:3,NA), 50, replace = T),
                 c3 = sample(c(0:3,NA), 50, replace = T), c4 = sample(c(0:3,NA), 50, replace = T))

head(df)
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  0  0  1  0
2  3  0  2  1
3  2  3 NA NA
4  0 NA NA  1
5 NA  1  1  3
6 NA NA  2  1
```

When c4 is 0, I'd like to replace it with the next available non-NA value in c3. If c3 is NA, then c2 and so on.

I'm trying to learn how to do it, so don't just throw in the answer! If it's alright, suggest possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Expected output:

```
head(df)
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  0  0  1  1 # This would be the only difference with the head output from above
2  3  0  2  1
3  2  3 NA NA
4  0 NA NA  1
5 NA  1  1  3
6 NA NA  2  1
```

Comment: Well, c4 is not 0 so not replacement needs to be made.

Comment: `df$c4 <- apply(df,1,function(x) {
    ifelse(x[4]==0, x[!is.na(x)][length(x[!is.na(x)])-1], x[4])
})`?

Comment: What if the next non `NA` value is zero like row9 of your `df`?

Comment: I forgot that. @Abdou, your solution works perfectly but now that I think of it, I need to get the next non-NA, non-zero values available. I'm gonna try to adapt your code to that.

Comment: Yes @m0h3n, you're right.

Comment: @Abdou, now that I think of it, the solution is still incomplete. For example what if a row is ``NA, NA, NA, 0``, then `x[!is.na(x)][length(x[!is.na(x)])-1]` will assign an NA instead of a 0.

Comment: `max.col` is often a good one for this circumstance - something like: `df$c4[which(df$c4==0)] <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df[1:3]), "last"))][which(df$c4==0)]`

Comment: @m0h3n I'm sorry I didn't respond correctly. Actually you're right. I'd want the non-NA, non-zero value available in order from c4 to c1.

Comment: @cimentadaj, actually the problem is when c4 is 0 while everything else is `NA`. What do you do in such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it *without* looping through each row:

```
c4 <- ncol(df)
inds <- max.col(!is.na(df[,-c4]) & df[,-c4]!=0, "last")
zeroinds <- which((df[,c4]==0)==T)
df[zeroinds,c4] <- df[cbind(zeroinds,inds[zeroinds])]

head(df, 10)

   # c1 c2 c3 c4
# 1   0  0  1  1
# 2   3  0  2  1
# 3   2  3 NA NA
# 4   0 NA NA  1
# 5  NA  1  1  3
# 6  NA NA  2  1
# 7   0  3 NA NA
# 8  NA NA  2  2
# 9   2  3  0  3
# 10  2  3  0  1
```

Here is how:

1. `c4` as the last column
2. We find the first non-NA and non-zero value per row before `c4`
3. Find those rows with zero in `c4` and put it in `zeroinds`
4. Replace zeros at `zeroinds` with the first non-NA and non-zero value per row

Comment: @cimentadaj Please note that in your data frame, there are few rows in which there is no non-NA, non-zero  after zero in `c4` value like row41.

Comment: Yeah, but in my real problem there is. This was a really smart solution. It helped a lot and even more because I understand it.